# ROR 3 : Event Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, railscasts

I am new to rails and i need some help working with calendar

I generated a scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold abc event_name:string  event_date:date  content:string
```

Now i can create events for a particular date and give some description.

I looked at Ryan Bate's rails cast video for  [calendar](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars).  But the plugin didn't work for me.

Then i followed: https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar (shown in the video) and followed the instructions.

With this i can create a calendar but it is just blank. How can i add my events objects created into the calendar for their respective dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use
[Fullcander](https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar)

Comment: Thanks.. that works. But when i try to include the code into my rails application. I can create, update, delete events but the calendar is not shown. any ideas?

Comment: I have tried to use this calendar but when I make a new event and move it to another day, then change the month view and back. The event disappears, even though it's still in the database. Weird